# Reducing a JSON file size in Webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack, bundle

I am trying to optimise my Webpack bundle and I have identified a large chunk of data that is being bundled from one of my dependencies. The dependency is [world-countries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/world-countries), which is just a huge JSON array of objects containing country data. I am however only using a fraction of this data in my app (a simple React app).

So what I am thinking is that I want to add *something* into my Webpack config that will effectively let me map the large objects down into just the properties I am using, and avoid having all the rest of the data end up in my bundle.

My only idea currently on how to do this would be to write a node script that runs postinstall or prebuild that imports the module, maps it and saves it back out to disk in a new JSON file. Then that JSON file is what my app imports.

I'm looking for any advice or ideas on the best way to implement this, preferably in a way that doesn't affect my apps code and is just part of the Webpack config.

Comment: Your app always will use the same subset? Do you use json-loader

Comment: Yes I do always use the same subset. No to json-loader, it was added as part of core Webpack in >= 2.0.0 so it's not needed.

Comment: If it is always the same country, copy to your project what you need

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean that it is always the same country. I use the data from multiple countries (or all of them), but it's always the same 4 fields from the country object that I need. It's that the library provides 30+ fields on each country object which are just bloating my bundle. I don't want to be maintaining an exhaustive list of countries inside of my project.

Comment: @TimothyBailey have you found a solution?

Comment: @BettySt, I never got a good answer here on an automated way to handle this, so ended up doing what I suggested in my original question and I wrote a small script that is run on postinstall that imports and maps the object from the countries dependancy into a new json file in my src folder. Then only the generated json file gets bundled by webpack, not the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom loader which will be applied on the Jason import, inside it filter out what you need.

Answer (score 0):

i am using [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) now to create only the JSON I need. In my example i am using the countries from [country-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-data):

Webpack config:

```
import { countries } from 'country-data';

...

plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    COUNTRIES: webpack.DefinePlugin.runtimeValue(function() {
      return JSON.stringify(countries.all.filter(function (c) {
        // Has "United Kingdom" twice, @see https://github.com/OpenBookPrices/country-data/issues/72
        var assigned = c.status === 'assigned';
        // cleanup JSON
        ['countryCallingCodes', 'languages', 'currencies', 'emoji', 'ioc', 'alpha3', 'status'].forEach(function (key) {
          delete c[key];
        });
        return assigned;
      }));
    }),
  }),
]
```

You then can use `COUNTRIES` in your code!